# rbind.fill in parallel with foreach

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rbind

I am trying to run the function **importTraj** from openair in parallel because I have a bunch of files to read. That is basically the code. However, every time I try to run it in parallel I get the error **Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'rbind.fill' not found"**. After that, I have decided to rewrite that function (importTraj) and turns out that I just replaced the **rbind.fill** function to the **rbind** function and everything is ok with the parallel execution. I'd like to know why it seems that I cannot use the **rbind.fill** with **foreach** in parallel. Also, if I use the *.combine* option in the **foreach** with the **rbind.fill** function I get the same error.

Thanks in advance!

```
cores<-detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(cores)

registerDoParallel(cl)

path<-"~/OpenAirWD/pheno2013/500M/"

# list all files
files<-list.files(path=path)


traj <- foreach( i=1:length(files), .combine='rbind' ) %dopar%
{
    importTraj(site = files[i], year='', local=path)
}
```

Comment: I think you need to carry the ```plyr``` package into each core in the foreach loop (e.g. ```.packages=c("plyr")```)

Comment: Also you can get huge speedup using the `dplyr` package and using the function `rbind_all` or `rbind_list`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! Thanks so much!